# How to position 2 Views relative to each other?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to position 2 views relative to each other but not simply w.r.t the top, bottom, left or right but in a *proportionate way*. Let me explain. Here are 4 scenarios of positioning:

[image]

Of these, 2) and 4) are easy to do and have in-built support provided by the standard layout containers such as RelativeLayout, ConstraintLayout but my current task requires a positioning depicted in scenarios 1)/3)

A simple solution to this problem involves setting different left/top margins for both the Views w.r.t parent but this means if the need arises to place both the Views together to some other position, all the margins shall have to change.

Instead, what I would like is to have some sort of relative positioning arrangement between these 2 views that keeps them relatively at "right" distance no matter where they are placed as a unit in the parent.

How can I achieve the same? An efficient solution(with flattened hierarchy, no view hacks) would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want them to change at run time?

Comment: @AvinashJoshi : No. I want to position them in XML once

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using constraint layout checkout below XML code for Point 3.(Same point 2 will be implemeted let me know if you have query)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonA"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:text="Add"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/buttonA"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/buttonA"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/buttonA"
            android:text="Add"
    />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
```

Please check out below code this is kind of patch but works fine.Here we can put big block to relative to small block.As we have used constraint so will be stick together no matter wherever you put. let me know if i did any thing wrong.

Here we use one dummyView and also `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"` for making it relative value  changes from 0 to 1 like 1 means 100% stating left to small block smae way 0.5 means 50% from starting small blobk to left.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonA"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:text="Add"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/dummyView"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/buttonA"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/buttonA"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/buttonA"
              app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/buttonA"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/dummyView"
            android:text="Add"
    />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: No, this only works in the special case when the View needs to be positioned relative to the mid of width/height of the other View. wouldn't work for general positioning!

Comment: Okay, I have update my Answer,Please look into it and let me know if there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

*An efficient solution(with flattened hierarchy, no view hacks) would be appreciated.*, You can use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) with [guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html).

- guidelines have `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent` attribute making them responsive to the screen size.
- you can use it while adding your buttons the `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent` and `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent` attributes (not mandatory, you can constraint your views to the guidelines but I believe that it is more simple).

**Here is an example for your wanted layout with flattened hierarchy:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".1"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".3" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".5" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".4" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".45" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**It will look like this(I am adding screenshot from the preview for better understanding guidelines):**

[image]

This was just an example but with those tools, you can create your layout however you would like to.

---

### Some extra information

- My solution does not contain any fixed size dimensions on my views, this will make the layout responsive(no need to build a layout for every screen size)
- You may also find [ConstraintLayout: Circular Positioning](https://medium.com/devnibbles/constraintlayout-circular-positioning-9489b11cb0e5) related to your question, but I don't think that this is the best thing for you in this specific case.

Comment: As I understand, in your solution, I would have to move all the Guidelines if I needed to shift the 2 Views as a unit diagonally in any direction. While moving all the guidelines, I would also have to ensure that the relative distance between the guidelines remains the same. Third, the calculation mapping of the guidelines to the new position would become a bit complicated.

Comment: *As I understand, in your solution, I would have to move all the Guidelines if I needed to shift the 2 Views as a unit diagonally in any direction*, you can place it inside fragment and move your fragment in your layout. But maybe consider checking the circular positioning as mentioned in my answer, after seeing your comment i belive it may fit to your use case after all.

Comment: Or, what I was dreading....Have a custom `ViewGroup` that supports composition with 2 Views and having custom attributes that facilitate specifying the relative position dimensioning. And if the size of any of the views change, layout()/invalidate() the parent as well to recalculate the relative positioning. Quite a bit of work!

Comment: That's a lot of work because you want something very specific, as far as I know, you can either use guidelines or use `ConstraintLayout: Circular Positioning`, If you will be able to find something better comment me here so I could learn it as well.